# "New Jekyll Page" not rendering default css.stylesheet : Only index.html works fine

Tags: css, jekyll, stylesheet, github-pages

I am quite new to Jekyll & webdesign in general. So far I have followed the regular instructions on how to build a new page with jekyll. It all sounds fairly simple in theory. But in practice I experience issues that are just not explained in the theory.

Below I try to be as descriptive as possible:

## Directory structure:

```
├── _includes
│           ├── footer.html
│           ├── head.html
│           ├── header.html
│           └── scripts.html
├── _layouts
│           └── default.html
├── _site
│     └── ...
│
├── css
│     └── style.css
├── fonts
│     └── ...
├── img
│     └── ...
├── js
│     └── ...
│
├──_config.yml
│ 
├──_gitignore.txt
│
├── CNAME
│ 
├── index.html
│ 
└── new_page.md
```

## What I did so far?

1) `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` added to head.html: chek!

#### Structure `<head>`:

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="{{ site.description }}">
  <meta name="author" content="{{ site.author }}">



  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Add icon library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

2) default.html in _layouts folder: chek!

#### Structure `default.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    {% include head.html %}

    <!-- The #page-top ID is part of the scrolling feature - the data-spy and data-target are part of the built-in Bootstrap scrollspy function -->

    <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
        {% include header.html %}

    {{ content }} 

        {% include footer.html %}
        {% include scripts.html %}
    </body>
</html>
```

3) index.html in rootdirectory: chek! **(homepage is working fine!)**

4) new_page.md in rootdirectory: chek! **(css is not rendering!)**

tryed new_page.html: not working either :(

5) YAML front matter in new_page.md: chek!

6) layout in YAML front matter links to default: chek!

7) When I inspect the new_page url: http://127.0.0.1:4000/boilerplate/about/ I notice the `<head>` is fully structured with link to css.stylesheet.

#### Structure `_config.yml`:

```
# ----------------------- #
#      Main Configs       #
# ----------------------- #

url: http://werkbaar.net
baseurl: /boilerplate/
title: WerkBaAr
email: aline@werkbaar.net
author: aline
description: > # ""
copyright:
credits: 'Credits: '
port: 4000

# ----------------------- #
#    Jekyll & Plugins     #
# ----------------------- #

plugins:
  #  - jekyll-seo-tag
  #  - jekyll-sitemap


# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
permalink: pretty

# ----------------------- #
#   3rd Party Settings    #
# ----------------------- #

social:
  - title: twitter
    url:
  - title: github
    url:
  - title: linkedin
    url:
```

Link to Repo: https://github.com/bomengeduld/boilerplate/tree/gh-pages
Link to actual website: werkbaar.net

Comment: Great start with Jekyll! Hang in there. Here are some useful scripts: http://jekyllcodex.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in how you are including the CSS files in your `head.html` include. Lines [#12](https://github.com/bomengeduld/boilerplate/blob/gh-pages/_includes/head.html#L12) and [#15](https://github.com/bomengeduld/boilerplate/blob/gh-pages/_includes/head.html#L15):

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

They are using a *relative* path, which means that when you go to a page that is in a sub-folder of your site, like `werkbaar.net/about/`, the browser expects the css files to be located at `werkbaar.net/about/css/bootstrap.min.css` and `werkbaar.net/about/css/style.css` respectively.

An easy way to fix this, is to start with a `/` when declaring your CSS files, so that you tell the browser to start from the root of your website.

e.g.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hi Caio, thank you for looking into this. Unfortunately, it didn't work out as planned. When I place the / the css of my index.html does not work anymore. And it doesnt change anything to new_page.md. What could it be?

Comment: @GinoJanLudikhuyze It seems you have another issue. In your `_config.yml` you defined `baseurl: /boilerplate/` - remove that line entirely as your site starts on the root

Comment: Well, when i place the / at <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> the css doesnt render in index.html

Comment: I just erased **/boilerplate/** from **config.yml** and placed like suggested the **<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">**... it only makes the issues worser. **index.html** doesnt show style

Comment: Can you commit these changes and push it to GitHub? I suspect there's something odd on running Jekyll locally on your machine.

Comment: Yes, that is quite a flaw of jekyll. I noticed it before with different code structures. It works now, thanks for reminding to chek it out when pushed.

Comment: I just inspected it. It might be because the source of the images also needs a / at the beginning of the path.

Comment: Exactly the same issue you had with the .css files... e.g. `src="img\logo_200x38px_t.png"` you need to insert an `/` before the images as to not use relative paths. Also should be `/` and not `\\` as you are using

Comment: The sad thing is, that I cant work on my website locally... Do you have any clue of why jekyll is not working locally? Maybe i should start another question for this?

Comment: How are you invoking Jekyll locally on your machine? What URL are you testing it with? `http://127.0.0.1:4000` or something else?

Comment: Remove the `boilerplate` from the URL... You don't need it anymore (remember you removed the `baseurl` from the config?) i.e. To test your website locally you should go to `http://127.0.0.1:4000`

Comment: Its how it opens when i use jekyll serve.. If I do it without boilerplate it doesnt work and I get a error page.

Comment: Could you type what is the command you use to start Jekyll? Is it simply `jekyll serve` or something else?

Comment: it is just jekyll serve

Comment: Caio. Thank you. I just had to reboot my localhost to make it work.

Comment: Oh that’s great!! :)